# Cat stopped burying poop in litterbox

Tags: cats, behavior, health, toilet-training, arthritis

My 15 year old cat, who has arthritis, has stopped burying her poop in the litterbox. Shes had arthritis for a few years and she's always buried her poop but has stopped doing so for a couple of months now. Nothing in her environment has changed, that I'm aware of. We have two other cats who she doesnt care for, but they've been with us for fifteen years as well. Do you know why a cat would stop burying--could it be related to her arthritis, is it something psychological, etc? How can I get her to start burying again?...it stinks!

Answer (score 1):

Very well could be from arthritis, you can always add arm and hammer baking soda to the litter to reduce smell or just pick it up once she poops. There are also self cleaning litter boxes that clean the litter after a pee or poop (though some cats get scared of these).

Have you changed the litter at all?